# Angular big table freeze web page while search

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, freeze

Need search on HTML table, search work perfectly, but very and very slowly and freeze web page when load and search. Table need in HTML file, NOT FROM SERVER, only in file. How to improve performance?

Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('jsSearch', []);

app.controller('FilterTable', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.result = [];
    $scope.basic_table = false;
    $scope.result_table = true;
    $scope.ishidden = false;
    $scope.totalDisplayed = 20;

    $scope.loadMore = function () {
        $scope.totalDisplayed += 20;
    };

    $scope.init = function(event, table_id) {


        var target = angular.element('#' + table_id);
        angular.forEach(target.children()[1].children, function(tr) {
            entry = [];
            angular.forEach(tr.children, function(td) {
                entry.push(td.innerHTML);
            });
            $scope.result.push(entry);



        })
        target.innerHTML = ''
    };

    $scope.search = function(event, table_id) {

         var dataValue = event.target.attributes.id.value;

    };

    $scope.filter_count = function(event, table_id) {
        $scope.ishidden = true;
        if($scope.count_value) {
            $scope.basic_table = false;
            $scope.result_table = true;
        }

        if($scope.string_value) {
            $scope.basic_table = false;
            $scope.result_table = true;
        }



        else {
            $scope.basic_table = false;
            $scope.result_table = true;
        }


        $scpopearray_length = $scope.result.length;
         $scope.ishidden = false;
    };
}]);

app.filter('returnCount', function () {
    return function (item, count_value) {
        return item.slice(0, count_value);
};

});
```

Full App:
[Link](http://rghost.ru/7t4TcjhxH)

[App on hosting](http://sirnov.hol.es)

Comment: That is not how you create a table in angular. Check ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are parsing the song table in the DOM to extract the song data - if you absolutely have to have the song data as an HTML table then this will work, but your code will be much cleaner if you can save the song data as an array and assign that array to $scope.result directly, rather than parsing from the DOM. The parsing process also is also quite slow and means the page is unresponsive for a few seconds after loading.

I can't see how the two ng-change listeners on string_value and count_value are affecting anything on the page - removing them speeds up the filtering significantly.

Apart from that what's slowing down the interaction here is the DOM modification every time the filter is changed. As long as the whole result table is in the DOM and being modified it will be slow, and I can't imagine having all of the songs visible in one long list is useful to the user either. I'd suggest a UX change - switch count to a drop-down, with options of, say, 100, 50, 20, and 10, and default it to 100.

With the ng-change attributes removed from the inputs and a maximum of 100 entries visible the filtering is pretty fast.